# Prometheus - how to retrieve first metrics timestamp

Tags: timestamp, prometheus, metrics

I am performing a query against some metric with a time range, say

`sum_over_time(my_metrics{my_filter=~"filter_regex"}[4d])`

What I am looking for is a way to determine if returned metrics were available for all 4 days. I want to bypass all returned values that were being gathared for less than 4 days.

It would be easy iy I knew what the first metric timestamp was.
Is there any other way to acheive this?

Comment: Prometheus has no the corresponding functionality. Try using `lifetime` function from [MetricsQL](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/wiki/MetricsQL): `lifetime(my_metrics{my_filter=~"filter_regex"}[4d])`